# Quantum Algorithm for Linear interpolation

Tags: quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra

Let $f$ : {$0, 1, . . . , M − 1$} $→$ {$0, 1, . . . , M − 1$} be a function of the form $f(x) = ax ⊕ b$, for
$a$ $∈$ {$0, 1, . . . , M − 1$} and $b$ $∈$ {$0, 1, . . . , M − 1$}, where $⊕$ is the sum modulo M. Assuming
a reduced oracle for $f$, I'm trying to find a quantum algorithm that finds out the number $a$ with the
minimum number of queries.

I'm not sure how to do this - I thought that perhaps the function's periodic so we could maybe use Shor's algorithm for period finding - but I don't know how to extend it to a reduced oracle.

Comment: How is "reduced oracle" defined in this case?

Comment: The reduced oracle is a unitary gate $V_f$ acting on only a single input. $V_f = \sum_{x=0}^{M-1} e^{(2\pi i f(x))/M} |x> <x| $

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to recover $a$ within a single query.

Applying $V_f$ on the uniform superposition, it yields:
$$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}\begin{align}
V_f\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\sum_{y=0}^{M-1}\ket{y}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\sum_{y=0}^{M-1}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}f(x)}\langle x|y\rangle\ket{x}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}f(x)}\ket{x}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}ax}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}b}\ket{x}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}b}}{\sqrt{M}}\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}ax}\ket{x}\\
\end{align}$$
Up to an irrelevant global phase $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}b}$, this is exactly $QFT\ket{a}$, where $QFT$ is the $M$-dimensional Quantum Fourier Transform. Applying its inverse thus yield $\ket{a}$.

Note that the oracle you use is quite limited: $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\mathrm{i}\pi}{M}b}$ will always come up as a global phase, so it will always be irrelevant (as long as you can't apply the controlled version of this oracle). Notably, it is impossible to recover $b$ using this oracle, no matter how many queries you issue to the oracle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we are not sure whether the function is periodic. In this case periodic would mean $\exists k\neq 0: \forall x\in 0,...,M-1:f(x)=f(x+k)$. A naive counterexample would be a function with a=1, b=0.

Especially in case $f$ is not periodic, we have:
$$f(x)-f(y)= ax+b - (ay+b) = ax-ay = a(x-y)$$
This means with two evaluations we can find the value of $a$ and $b$.

If the function would be periodic, it would mean the function is not bijective $\implies$ a is not coprime to $M$. We could try to factor $M$ hoping to find $a$ in that case.